# Stack smashing detected during fread on binary file in C

Tags: c, image, binary, fread, stack-smash

UPDATE IN BOTTOM====

So a while ago I made the following function, which I successfully used to get the grey values from images (*w x h* dimension) that were converted to .bin-files. It just gives an array of all pixel values.
*It was, however, not as a function like this but put in the main() immediately.*

```
// read the BIN-file as grayscale image
void decodeBIN(const char* filename, short image[], int w, int h){
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char buffer[16]; // no specific size attributed
    FILE *ptr;

    ptr = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!ptr){
        printf("\nUnable to open file!\n"); // error
    }

    while (!feof(ptr)){
        fread(buffer,2,1,ptr); // read w bytes to buffer
        image[i] = buffer[1];
        //printf("%u ", image[i]); // DEBUG
        i++;
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    printf("\nBinary image read (npixels: %i).\n", i-1); // DEBUG
}
```

I decided to expand the code, so I rewrote it to the previous function and put it in a separate file for functions and also made a header file. The extra file for functions and the header file work 100% so that's not the issue. Now, this code does not work anymore and I get a stack smashing error. Some variables called after this function have also jumped to another value, so I figured the problem was with the buffer (I didn't know about the correct size for the buffer, but it worked...). After some experimentation and testing, I came up with the following function. I replaced the buffer with a char array named image2 to simply try and test it:

```
void decodeBIN(const char* filename, short image[], int w, int h){
    int i = 0, res;
    char image2[];
    FILE *ptr;

    ptr = fopen(filename, "rb"); //"MySnap_20180327-2239-010.bin"
    if (!ptr){
        printf("\nUnable to open file!\n"); // error
    }

    res = fread(image2,1,w*h,ptr) // need to read w*h pixels

    while (i < w*h){ // DEBUG
        printf("%i ", (int)image2[i]); // DEBUG
        i++;
    }
    printf("\nRead %u bytes\n", res); // DEBUG
    fclose(ptr);
    printf("Binary image read (npixels: %i).\n", i); // DEBUG
}
```

I'm a bit lost in how it used to work and all of a sudden when I move the code from main() to a function it stops working, so any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Disclaimer: I'm aiming to write this with the help of as few libraries as possible

===== UPDATE:

After the answer of @alainmerigot I got this code, which helped with getting the correct values:

```
void decodeBIN(const char* filename, unsigned char image[], int w, int h){
    int i = 0, res;
    FILE *ptr;

    res = fread(image,sizeof(char),w*h,ptr) // need to read w*h pixels
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

The segmentation fault and jumped variables are still in place though, so here a more upper-level oversight of what I'm doing:

```
char filenamePathed["[path of file]/file.bin"];
short img1[npixels]; // npixels = w*h
printf("i_file: %i\n", i_file); // correct value
decodeBIN(filenamePathed, img_curr, w, h); // decode bin
printf("i_file: %i\n", i_file); // value jumped
while (i < npixels){
    img1[i] = (short)img_curr[i];
    i++;
}
```

Perhaps it is good to know that I'm doing this iteratively for multiple files (time series)? I also need it to end up in a (short) format (or integer, but eventually needs to be memory-efficient and pixels have a range of 0-255 so int is a bit abundant imo).

Comment: you `fread()` into a nonexisting buffer (`image2[]` points to nowhere)

Comment: Thanks for your very fast comment! This was actually an honest mistake, but this did not fix it in the end

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your second function is that you write in array `image2` while no space has been reserved for it. Declaring `char image2[];` only says that an array exists and that the address of this array can be found in var `image2`, but no space is associated with it, hence the problem.

You can associate space with this array by several means.

Using permanent storage in the heap

`image2 = malloc(x*y);  // but do not forget to free(image2) at the end of the function`

Using temporary storage in the stack (space is automatically freed when leaving the function).

`image2 = alloca(x*y);  // slightly faster than malloc and do not require to free() the image`

But the best is to use a array with parametrized size (since C99). Your array should be declared as

`char image2[w*h]; // will use the value of w and h to define array size`

If you want to do other things than printing the image values in your function, you should store the image in permanent memory and have a mean to know the address of the array in your program. This is probably what you intended and is the reason why you have `short image[]`  in your parameter list.

The solution is just simply to use `image` instead of `image2` in  `fread()`.

But, the declaration of `image` should be coherent and image should be an array of `char` not `short`.

Beware also of declarations. In your first function, the image is an array of `unsigned char` and in the second an array of `char`. While the storage size is identical and `fread()` will store the same values, they are not equivalent. If used in an arithmetic context, `image[i]` will be interpreted differently and the results will likely be different. In general, images are `unsigned`.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate explanation, liked that a lot.
I applied your solution and ended up with the following:
`void decodeBIN(const char* filename, unsigned char image[], int w, int h){
        int i = 0, res;
        FILE *ptr;

        res = fread(image,sizeof(char),w*h,ptr) // need to read w*h pixels
       fclose(ptr);
    }`
Even though this does give a correct output, I still get segmentation fault (core dumped) and jumping variables afterwards. Does this indicate it's in the code following it?

Comment: Difficult to say. The function should be correct this way if `image` is allocated. Problems should be in the rest of your code.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Could you take a quick look at the update for me? Perhaps there's something useful there?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was with the allocation of `image`, although I'm not sure why it was wrong.
I used to allocate it with `unsigned char image[npixels];` and the solution to the error appeared to be `unsigned char image[npixels*7];`
Somehow it works, but if anyone has an explanation, please do so :)